# Prove $\alpha = [X] \in L = \mathbb F_p[X]/\langle \pi \rangle$ is a primitive n'th root of unity in $L$ and this implies $p^d \equiv 1 \mod n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

[My rephrasing, JL]

Let $p$ be a prime and let $n$ a positive integer coprime to $p$. Let further $\Phi_n(X)$ denote the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial, and let $\pi\in\Bbb{F}_p[X]$ be an irreducible factor of degree $d$ of $\Phi_n(X)$. Let $L=\Bbb{F}_p[X]/\langle \pi\rangle$ be the quotient field. Consider the element $\alpha=[X]\in L$. Show that it is a primitive $n$th root of unity in $L$. Further explain, why this implies that $p^d\equiv1\pmod n$.

---

Prove $\alpha = [X] \in L = \mathbb F_p[X]/\langle \pi\rangle$ is a primitive n'th root of unity in $L$ and this implies $p^d \equiv 1 \mod n$, where $\pi \in \mathbb F_p[X]$ is irreducible and $\pi \mid \phi_n(X) \in \mathbb F_p[X]$.

I know $p \nmid n$ and $\phi_n(X)$ denote the n'th cyclotomic polynomial.

I've proven that $L$ is a field with $p^d$ elements.

$\pi \mid \phi_n(X)$ allows us to write $\pi g=\phi_n(X)$ for some $g \in \mathbb F_p[X]$. $\langle a_d^{-1} \pi \rangle = \langle \pi \rangle$ tells us that $\alpha^d= 1\in L$. Also $[\phi_n(X)] = [\pi g]$, but I can't proceed from here.

Comment: I think I understand what you are asking. Your question may benefit from a bit of editing though. Most notably, you use the quantity $\pi$ on your first line, but only explain what it means on the third.

Comment: I've edited a bit, thanks

Comment: I edited it a bit more. Consider the following from the point of view of the reader of your question. In order to explain what $\alpha$ is you first have to explain what $L$. So the reader prefers to see the definition of $L$ before that of $\alpha$. In order to define $L$, you have to tell the reader what $\pi$ is, so that should preferrably come **before** the definition of $L$. But to tell the reader what $\pi$ is, you need to first introduce $\Phi_n(X)$. To that end you need to tell what $n$ and $p$ are.

Comment: I was a bit strict there, and occasionally we can relax these rules a bit. Most notably, when the context helps. Yours was just a particularly hasty case, which is why I wanted to go into this level of detail.  I know it very well that  translating a question from ones own language will create extra difficulties here, so we the non-natives are given some slack here. Do try take this into account in the future, and take a look at the question with the eyes of a reader, who lacks all the context at the beginning. Will answer your question soon :-)

Comment: Thanks, I will use your question as a guideline for questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Extended hints (that's my style):

We are first to prove that $\alpha^n=1_L$, and that $n$ is the smallest positive integer with this property.

- At the level of cosets of polynomials the equation $\alpha^n=1$ means that the cosets $X^n+\langle \pi\rangle$ and $1+\langle\pi\rangle$ are the same. In other words, the coset of their difference, $X^n-1$ should be the zero coset. Yet in other words, we first need to show that the polynomial $X^n-1$ is divisible by $\pi$. Why is that the case?
- Next we need to show that if $0<\ell<n$, then $\alpha^\ell\neq1_L$. As in the preceding bullet point, this is equivalent to showing that $X^\ell-1$ is **not** divisible by $\pi$ for any such $\ell$. Note that we only need to worry about the cases where $\ell\mid n$. This is because the first bullet implies that the order of $\alpha$ is a factor of $n$. This step is actually a tad tricky, because you need the fact that $\gcd(n,p)=1$. That condition implies that $X^n-1$
  has no multiple factors (how?), and you will need that here (why?)

The other part of the exercise is the claim that $n\mid p^d-1$. This is now easy if you remember the following bits:

- The group $L^*$ is cyclic of order $p^d-1$, because the multiplicative grops of finite fields are always cyclic.
- Lagrange's theorem from the theory of finie (cyclic) groups. Actually we already used this in the second bullet while showing that we only need to look at the cases $\ell\mid n$.

Comment: The second bullet may need to be expanded a bit, or split into several parts. Thinking... Probably depends on whether you have covered suitable auxiliary results/lemmas that come to the fore here.

Comment: $\pi \mid X^n - 1$ because $X^n - 1 = \prod_{d \mid n} \phi(X)_d = \phi(X)_n \cdot f$ which under homomorphism yields $X^n - 1 = \sigma(\phi(X)_n)\cdot\sigma(f)$, and by assumption $\pi \mid \sigma(\phi(X)_n) \Rightarrow \pi \mid X^n - 1$ in $\mathbb F_p[X]$ ?? This implies $X^n - 1 \in \langle \pi \rangle \Rightarrow [X^n-1] = [0]$

Comment: I have no idea about step 2 :(

Comment: First step - correct! Yeah, the second step is the most difficult. Here $\ell\mid n$. So if $\pi\mid X^\ell-1$ and also
$\pi\mid\Phi_n(X)\mid (X^n-1)/(X^\ell-1)$, then $\pi^2\mid X^n-1$. But $\gcd(X^n-1,D(X^n-1))=1$, so $X^n-1$ has no multiple factors in $\Bbb{F}_p[X]$. If $p\mid n$, then $D(X^n-1)=0$, so this step would fail.

Comment: I was half hoping that you might have had an earlier exercise that helps with the second step.

Comment: Why does $\phi_n(X) \mid (X^n - 1)/(X^l - 1)$ ?
$$\frac {(X^n-1)} {(X^l-1)} = \frac {\prod_{d\mid n} \phi_d(X)}  {\prod_{d\mid l} \phi_d(X)} $$ Ahh it is because if $d \mid l$ then $d \mid n$ So every term in denominator cancel.

Comment: But $\pi^2 \mid X^n - 1$ ?. We already know $\pi \mid X^n -1$. This is true because ?

Comment: We are trying to prove that if $\pi\mid X^\ell-1$, then  $\pi^2\mid X^n-1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand your reasoning. However I've never read that $gcd(X^n-1, D(X^n-1)) = 1$ should imply that $X^n-1$ has no multiple factors. I guess this is proved somewhere else, not in my textbook.

Comment: If $p(X)^2\mid f(X)$ then $p(X)$ is also a factor of $f'(X)$ by the standard rules of taking derivatives. Derivatives of polynomials make sense over $\Bbb{F}_p$ as well (and the product rule holds, which is all we need here).